# Where to write Script which fires immidiately on changing DropDown Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I've a web application on asp.net using vb.net. On one of the UI Screens, there's a drop down having a post back on onSelectedIndexChange.

The problem is I want to block the entire UI as soon as there's a onSelectedIndexChange and wish to unblock it after the event is completed.

I tried experimenting putting an alert() in Page.Init but it's not firing as soon as I change the Value in DropDown. I even tried putting the alert() in the start on the onSelectedIndexChange method but it didn't work too.

Where should I write the script which fires as soon as I change the DropDown?

Comment: Why you have alert in page.Init, show us the code please

Comment: I don't have alert() in page.Init. I just put it there to check if it fires immediately after DropDown change event.

Comment: Can you please paste the code please.

Comment: Hey Prerit!! Code is not required right? Just a conceptual question! Which is the first function which will be invoked in case of post back!

Comment: Add javascript event onchange to dropdownlist by adding following in html tag of dropdown "onchange=alert('hello')"

Comment: I'm not using HTML control. I'm using ASP control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Try blockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#page) with jQuery

```
$( ".target" ).change(function() {
  $.blockUI({ message: '<h1>Just a moment...</h1>' });
});
```